# Display (syntax) trees in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I want to be able to display dynamic syntax trees on a webpage, possibly with a jQuery component. To show you what I mean, this

[image: Syntax tree]

is a syntax tree, and this is the general way I want it to be displayed.

**How do I build something like this with HTML and CSS?**

### edit: Solution

Just in case somebody who finds this question later is trying the same, here's what I did:

I ended up drawing the tree with Graphviz as an SVG, and then, moving the svg tree inside the DOM using some magic. That way I could still interact with the elements, e.g. drag&drop or hover/click events.

The result can be seen [here](http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de).

Comment: and wat is the question?

Comment: How do I build something like this with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try [d3](http://d3js.org/), it has a really good [tree visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [ArborJs](http://arborjs.org/), you can find an introduction [here](http://arborjs.org/introduction)

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems to do too much by itself. One of the requirements for my scenario is that the root node is always on top, daughter nodes are on the next level and so on.. But I'll look into it.